# How to use 3-Axial acceleration data for CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn

Currently, i am using 1-D acceleration by dividing data in 10 seconds segments and then making a test train split into these segments. But i am not sure how to use 3-D data, especially how to make test train split out this data because for each label there will 3 channel input.

**EDIT**
My dataset looks lie this :

[image: Data Set]

Right now I am only using `X-Axis`. I am segmenting `X-acc` in 200 samples and for each sample, I have an activity label. So now I have a number of segments and a label for each of these segments. After that, I am splitting these segments and their corresponding labels in **test train split**. This all works fine but no i want to use `Y-axis` and `x-axis` also. so now i will have three arrays each segmented in 200 samples, now i am not sure how toperform test train split.

**Note** Activity labels are not shown here, but there are total 6 labels and are one hot encoded.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? You ask a very broad question “how to use 3-D data”, and a very specific question about train test splitting. Which one do you want answered?

Comment: @kbrose Kindly see the edit